# dart angular2 - iteration in template

Tags: templates, angular, dart

I'd like to iterate each type of : `List<Map<String, List<String>>>` in my angular2 template.

How can i do that ?

I guess for the list I can do `<div *ngFor="let listItem of myListOfMap">`,
but I have no idea for the map inside.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just iterate over the keys of the map and then you can use the key to access the value:

```
<div *ngFor="let listItem of myListOfMap">
  <div *ngFor="let key of listItem.keys">
    {{key}} : {{listItem[key]}}
  <div>
</div>
```